# Finding the 3 largest number from array

Tags: python

Given an array with elements, find the largest 3 numbers, and need to return the 3 numbers in descending order. There is one function which will take arguments as array of numbers and return a list of 3 largest numbers.

```
def printnew3largest(arr):
    third = first = second = -sys.maxsize
    for i in range(0, len(arr)):
        if(arr[i] > first):
            third = second
            second = first
            first = arr[i]
        elif (arr[i] > second):
            third = second
            second = arr[i]
        elif (arr[i] > third):
            third = arr[i]
    print("Three largest numbers in descending order are ", first, second, third)
    
arr = [12, 13, 1, 10, 34, 1]
n = len(arr)
printnew3largest(arr)
```

So when I am running this code in my IDE it is giving me output but not sure why it is failing in Hackerank.

Any idea what wrong I am doing here?

Comment: Why not sort the list in descending order and pick the first three items afterwards?

Comment: I would suggest doing a sort, and just printing them. What happens if the list is shorter than 3?

Comment: `-sys.maxsize`? And what happens if your list (it's a list, not an array) contains the values `[-sys.maxsize-1,-sys.maxsize-2,-sys.maxsize-3]`?

Comment: `sorted(arr, reverse=True)[:3]` will do

Comment: You aren't returning anything from your function. You're just printing the output. The website you're using might need a `return` instead.

Comment: One reason not to sort first: this algorithm (if done correctly!) is O(n), and Python's `list.sort()` and `sorted()` are O(n log n).

Comment: As a note: [`heapq.nlargest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest) can do this for you.

Comment: One reason to sort first: `list.sort()` and `sorted()` are implemented in C and will be much faster than the equivalent code written in Python.

Comment: I do not see `import sys` in your code.

Comment: What is the requested output format of the question? Return a list of numbers? Just change the print to `return [first, second, third]`

Comment: The requested output is "Return a list of 3 largest numbers". So i need to return a list.

Comment: @neo So do it: `return [first, second, third]`...

Comment: Thanks so much let me try this. :-)